# sql query without subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to rewrite this query and I'm not allowed to use a subquery. I need to select the name and color of the parts that are heavier than the wheel.

```
SELECT name, color
FROM parts
WHERE weight > (SELECT weight FROM parts WHERE name="wheel");
```

This is the table:

PARTS

```
ID    NAME    COLOR     WEIGHT    
1     wheel   black     100
2     tire    black     50
3     gear    red       20
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ben probably - it does appear to be from a standard demo database

Comment: @user1285737 why are you not allowed to use a subquery?

Comment: Just a thought, MySQL views do not permit you to use subqueries in the view statement so maybe he needs a view?

Comment: @David: because the year is 1989, clearly ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join it with itself

```
SELECT parts_a.name, parts_a.color 
FROM parts parts_a, parts parts_b
WHERE parts_a.weight > parts_b.weight
   AND parts_b.name = "wheel"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with join.

```
SELECT a.name, a.color 
FROM parts as a left join parts as b on a.ID=b.ID
WHERE a.weight > b.weight
AND b.name = "wheel"
```

Comment: won't that only return the wheel row?

Answer (score -1):

I should write down this query without using subqueries 
SELECT C.pid
FROM Catalog C, Suppliers S
WHERE S.sname = ‘Yosemite Sham’ AND C.sid = S.sid
AND C.cost ≥ ALL (Select C2.cost
FROM Catalog C2, Suppliers S2
 WHERE S2.sname = ‘Yosemite Sham’ AND C2.sid = S2.sid)

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a particularly [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) .